# How can I use \w in double quoted string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm using Capistrano for deployment and I need to run a command for setting the correct environment in the .htaccess file on the server.

I do that with `sed` like this: `run "sed -i -r 's/APPLICATION_ENV \w+/APPLICATION_ENV #{stage}/' #{current_release}/public/.htaccess"`

My problem is that the `\w+` is escaped by Ruby/Cap and the regexp ends up trying to match only `w+`. If I use `\\w+` I end up with a regexp that attempts to match `\\w+`.

How can I have an interpolated double quoted string and successfully escape the `\w`? Do I really need to change to concatenation of single quoted string and variables?

Comment: you could try to just echo out your command. ```\\w+``` should result in ```\w+``` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my sysem your sample works but you could try it with one of these two (comment the ones out you don't use)

```
begin
  stage = "stage"
  current_release = "current_release"
  s = "sed -i -r 's/APPLICATION_ENV \\w+/APPLICATION_ENV #{stage}/' #{current_release}/public/.htaccess"
  s = "sed -i -r 's/APPLICATION_ENV #{"\\w+"}/APPLICATION_ENV #{stage}/' #{current_release}/public/.htaccess"
  s = "sed -i -r 's/APPLICATION_ENV #{92.chr}w+/APPLICATION_ENV #{stage}/' #{current_release}/public/.htaccess"
  puts s
  system s
rescue 
  puts $! 
  system('pause') 
end
```

Comment: It was just a newbfest from my side. My first attempt was without escaping the backslash, causing it not to work. Then when I tested with two backslashes, I did a `cat .htaccess`, but because that that folder is a symlink I got the old version of the file. And from there it just escalated.